# Emulating internal classes with constructor functions defined in seperate files

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm designing a front-end module. Because of familiarity with OO-style programming and .NET in general in my team, I'm relying heavily on constructor functions, each currently in its own file and own scope.

See the following example setup.

File `employee.js`:

```
(function(my) {
  "use strict";

  my.Employee = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = "John Doe";
  };
}(window["MyNamespace"]));
```

Another file `company.js`:

```
(function(my) {
  "use strict";

  my.Company = function(data) {
    var self = this, employees = [];

    self.name = data.name || "New company";

    self.spawnNewEmployee = function() {
      employees.push(new my.Employee());
    }    
  };
}(window["MyNamespace"]));
```

Important bit: my build process will bundle and minify these files into a final file. I have postponed deciding on a particular technology for doing so (which might be my actual problem, not sure).

The problem: `Employee` is available to anyone with access to `window["MyNamespace"]`, which is any script. However, I want to hide `Employee` to consumers outside my module, while keeping access to it from the `Company` constructor function.

In a C# or Java project there are `internal` classes. **Is there a idiomatic way to emulate internal classes with JavaScript constructor functions?** Or should I rely on a post-build step / bundling+minification tool to decide what gets exported to the global namespace? Or do I have things mixed up entirely?

Comment: The only way to "hide" things in _JavaScript_ is by capturing them in a closure (i.e. a common parent function which sets up external references to (or `return`s) the variables you want visible externally. I don't think you'll be able to do this across multiple files.

Comment: A module system (such as AMD, CommonJS or ES 6 modules) would be a partial solution. You would not be able to make it completely inaccessible, but it would not be in the global scope by default. Otherwise you would have to have your `Employee` function and your `Company` function in the same closed scope at definition time.

Comment: @PaulS. and nils, thx for those pointers. You triggered me to check how others solve this, and I found e.g. [KnockoutJS has a very specific solution for this](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/google-closure-compiler-utils.js) (or is it?).